# The fragments for my BottomNavigationView are not showing

Tags: android

I implemented a BottomNavigationView within an AppBarLayout but the fragments for the different icons aren't showing when they are selected.

[This is my xml file for the activity holding the fragments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Glfh5.png)

[This is the corresponding java file for the activity, I've tried logging some messages to debug but I can't seem to find the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukKn5.png)

[This is the fragment file for Search, Map's file is similar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C95zS.png)

When the activity is executed and the icons are clicked on, the fragment does not appear and nothing changes. I hope you guys can help me to figure out the issue, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is recommended to utilize the **Navigation component** along with BottomNavigationView for your implementation. While it is technically possible to achieve the desired functionality without the Navigation component, it would offer several benefits such as improved navigation handling and simplified code management. Incorporating the Navigation component with BottomNavigationView would provide a more efficient and structured solution.

Comment: I took your advice and introduced the navigation component along with the nav_graph, and after spending some time with trial and error as well as the triggering of functions, I finally got it to work. It's a whole different approach though, but I guess it still worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

xml code

````
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    app:startDestination="@id/homeFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
        android:name="com.example.myapp.HomeFragment"
        android:label="Home Fragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/searchFragment"
        android:name="com.example.myapp.SearchFragment"
        android:label="Search Fragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_search" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/profileFragment"
        android:name="com.example.myapp.ProfileFragment"
        android:label="Profile Fragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_profile" />

</navigation> ``` 

java code 
``` bottomNavView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_home:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, new HomeFragment())
                    .commit();
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_search:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, new SearchFragment())
                    .commit();
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_profile:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, new ProfileFragment())
                    .commit();
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}); ```
````